# SQL Reporting: percent on repartition graphs?

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2008

I've to create a graphic with some percent information:
[image]

The percentage can be either IN the graphic, outside of the of the pie chart(but it has to be near the corresponding part).

I didn't found how to do this in the report builder 3.0, do you know how I can achieve this?

Actually I've numbers(e.g. 3300, 3000, 400, I can certainly transform them in percent if needed).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your pie chart, right-click on any of the pie slices in Design mode and select Show Data Labels. You will see sample values display on your chart. Right-click one of the labels and select Series Labels Properties - you can then set font, color, formatting, etc. The default is to display inside the pie slice. If you need to control position, select one of the sample values and then see the Position property in the Properties window to adjust.

Comment: Thanks, it's stupid, but I was looking in chart properties, not in the right menu.

Comment: With charts, there are lots of places where properties are stashed. It's easy to get lost in there!